# A simple neural network for classifying datasets

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, federated-learning

I want to train a neural network that is as simple as possible, that is able to classify datasets.
I have 5 [MedMNIST](https://www.medmnist.com) datasets that each contain a number of labels, and with complex features.
I'm seeking a simple neural network solution that is able to be able to just identify the source of an image, without the need to learn all complex representations.
**Optional details for use case:**
This network will be used in a [federated learning](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/04/federated-learning-collaborative.html) scenario, where each node will train a simpler model that can classify it's own dataset, besides the model that classifies labels that it owns.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It sounds like you have a supervised problem with image features and five possible outcomes (corresponding to the dataset of origin). Do you see something to the problem beyond this?

Comment: What do you mean by “classifying dayasets”?

Comment: After the exit, it now sounds like your pipeline goes: `input image into first neural network > get predicted dataset label > input image into a second neural network developed on that particular dataset > use that second neural network to predict the label`. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Dave Yes that's sort of how my pipeline will be.

Comment: Then it seems like a rather standard five-class problem, right? Do you see additional complications?

Comment: I couldn't use any "simple" neural network that does this.  Even an architecture that is able to classify CIFAR10 couldn't do it. My constraint is training time, it needs to be as short as possible. Training a VGG or a ResNet isn't an option.

Comment: It’s not a given that a simple architecture will be able to achieve strong performance.

Comment: @Dave I understand that but I'm talking here about completely different datasets. I thought that simple feature extractors would be able to do perform well. I just had this idea/problem, I'll try to think about it more, my approach is probably not the optimal way, a pixel density distribution based classification seems plausible in my case. Thanks anyways. First time on Stack Exchange and it seems nice place to help and get help, I'll be staying here for a while it seems ^^.